# Bio chemistry to create heavy rain

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, biochemistry

My creature creates heavy rain simply by coming into contact with Earth’s atmosphere, its body producing several chemical compounds to produce this effect.
What are plausible bio chemicals for my organism to create heavy rain ?

Comment: Welcome Bala. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance to our ways. Enjoy the site.

Comment: By heavy rain, do you mean we'd need to make a compound climb up and then rain down as water or your creature's already in the sky and it only needs to "sweat" very profusely?

Comment: Do you mean "water" of a higher density than normal water, or just really intense rain?

Comment: Just really intense rain

Comment: Hello Bala. When you get a moment, please follow @ARogueAnt.'s suggestion and take our [tour] and read at least this [help/on-topic] page and this [help/dont-ask] page. Can you provide some details? Creating rain over one of Earth's poles is a LOT different than over the ocean at the equator. Can you specify just one location on Earth for us to use? Also, please specify exactly how much square acreage must experience rain. As you can imagine, continent-sized is a very different kettle of fish compared to a single city. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the only way i could maybe see it happening is if the creature was insanely big (like india sized) and the evaporated water in its breath condensed into quick little showers in a cold climate. Heavy rain requires forces on the scale of continents and with the energy of the sun, it doesn't just happen on its own. If you had a creature flying over already established clouds sweat silver iodide into them and seed them then maybe you can get a cloud or two to start raining but not much more, the clouds have to already be there.
There are no biochemicals that can seed rain, so either your creature sweats silver iodide (and even then it would just get its immediate surroundings, now if you have a flock of birds or locusts do that.....), or it has some form of magic.

Comment: Welcome yotam. Please take our [tour] and refer to our [help] for guidance. Enjoy the site.

Answer (score 1):

[Cloud seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_seeding) is, in fact, a real thing. Silver iodide is one possible chemical, but the article lists others.

Sprinkle suitable clouds with the right chemicals, and you might be able to trigger rainfall, or increase the rate at which it precipitates.

It cannot, however, conjure the clouds into being. The water needs to be already there, and if it ain't, then you can't create rain. Thin clouds won't produce monsoon rain. Obviously, you could carry the water up there with you, but then you're not really triggering a rainstorm via chemical mechanisms but merely vomiting, sweating or urinating profusely upon the land below.

Answer (score 0):

The creature is incredibly big and it's biochemistry is nearly fully water. Upon entering the atmosphere it burns up, but enough travels down to a point it can rain down.

Otherwise I really don't know how this would be feasible. The energy to create rain is a lot.
Light rain is already incredible. But heavy rain requires 10 to 50 mm (0.39 to 2 inch) of water over the area you want. If that is 'only' kilometer big, you need to have 10mm times 1km times 1km = 10 000 000 liters of water for an hour. That is an incredibly tiny area for the minimum amount of rain for, granted, not an insignificant time. Now I can continue about the amount of energy needed to get that into the sky and such, but it's safe to say its impossible for any creature's 'biochemistry' to generate enough energy to push up 10 million liters, or 10 million kilo of water into the sky. Especially with energy wasting ways like vaporising droplets to get them airborne.

The question is simply ridiculous, unless magical thinking or straightforward answers like "the creature is basically a falling rainstorm".